# Pressing tab while editing a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed

If you go to edit a comment, the tab order takes you to the "Save Edits" button, but then it skips the "Cancel" link and jumps down to "Active" (the answer sort method).

This wasn't expected.  I would expect <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> would take you to "Cancel" next.  Should this be considered a bug?

Comment: Testing this feature.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ, yay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tab order will be fixed on the edit comment form after the next build.

Answer (score 3):

This is because they are merely text, not links. Neither the "cancel" nor "help" anchors have a `href` attribute, so the browser doesn't consider them in tab order because they *don't go anywhere*. Could be easily fixed by adding a `href="#"` like the rest of the links (flag uses this).